# Newbie Question about adding an array element on a page (php script)

Tags: php, smarty

Apologize me if the question is unclear.

I'm a total newbie php user and I have this script that I want to edit.

The script have uses .tpl for the theme.

In the `memberprofile.tpl` there is the `first name` element `$profilearray[0].firstname` I want to add the result of this element also in another `.tpl` file called `docs.tpl`

I tried copying and pasting `` `$profilearray[0].firstname `` in `docs.tpl` but it did not work. 
I noticed that `docs.tpl` uses its own `$docsarray[0].xxx`

So guys any idea how to do this? because there are some information in the member profile that I would like to add them inside the docs page.

I tried playing with mysql but I don't know how to use the same element `firstname` for both `memberprofile` and `docs` tables

I'm sure there is an easy way to do it.

Here's the full code from `memberprofile.tpl`and I want to show some of these info in that theme `docs.tpl`

```
<p class="gray">
    {$lang112}: <b>{$profilearray[0].firstname}&nbsp;{$profilearray[0].lastname}</b><br>
    {$lang130}: <b>{$profilearray[0].birthday}</b><br>
    {$lang134}: <b>{if $profilearray[0].gender eq "1"}Male{elseif $profilearray[0].gender eq "0"}Female{/if}</b><br>                
    {$lang140}: <b>{$profilearray[0].city}</b> <br>
    {$lang139}: <b>{$profilearray[0].country}</b> <br>
    {$lang113}: <b>{insert name=get_stripped_phrase value=a assign=pdesc details=$profilearray[0].description}{$pdesc}</b> <br>
    {$lang259}: <b><a href="{$profilearray[0].url}" target="_blank">{$profilearray[0].url|stripslashes|truncate:20:"...":true}</a></b> <br>
    {$lang260}: <b>{insert name=get_time_to_days_ago value=var time=$profilearray[0].lastlogin}</b> <br>
    {$lang261}: <b>{insert name=get_time_to_days_ago value=var time=$profilearray[0].addtime}</b>
</p>
```

Comment: To which templating engine do those `.tpl` files belong to?

Comment: Looks like Smarty to me.

Comment: @hakre .tpl and the syntax this person is using is clearly smarty

Comment: BTW, it is clear that you are not a programmer, and i would suggest that you learn about variable scope (the reason why you have 2 variables named 2 different things in 2 different scripts) before posting here because the thing you are trying to do is not as easy as your thinking it should be

Answer (score 1):

Smarty has a tag you can google for called {include} that will do what you want.  http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.tpl  Use that tag on your docs.tpl file and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$profilearray
```

in your example is assigned to smarty template before the template is called in some fashion simmilar to this

```
            $smarty->assign('profilearray',$somearray);
```

you'll need to find what is setting that in your first file then make sure that is included in your second template call

but you should certainly read the [smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/) to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

To step back for a moment... There are two parts to all this. The first part is the PHP code which actually takes user input, queries the database, processes the data, etc. The second part is the TPL file. As much as possible, the TPL file should only be concerned with **presentation**, not with data-processing, data-cross-referencing, etc.

All that database-reading and cross-referencing should happen inside a plain PHP file, not inside the TPL.

In order to add "Author information" to the "Documents List" (or whatever you call `docs.tpl`) page, you need to find the PHP code which pulls up the list of documents. Find the PHP code where it says something like:

```
$smarty->assign('docsarray',$document_list);
```

Now what you want to do is pass *more* information to the smarty template (TPL file) so that it can display it. Something like:

```
for($document_list as $index => $doc){
    $owner = $doc['owner'];        // Get the owner of the document
    $profile = getProfile($owner); // Create one of the same things that go into $profilearray elsewhere
    $document_list[$index]['profile'] = $profile; // Modify original array
}
$smarty->assign('docsarray',$document_list);
```

Then go into `docs.tpl` and find where it displays information about each document, and add smarty template code to read from the new per-document information you added. (Check the [Smarty reference page](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/) for details.)

For example, if `docs.tpl` shows a table of documents, you might add a new column that shows the author's first/last name:

```
<tr>
    <td>{$docsarray[$index].title}</td>
    <td>{$docsarray[$index].created_date}</td>
    <!-- Next line is new -->
    <td>{$docsarray[$index].profile.firstname} {$docsarray[$index].profile.lastname}</td>
</tr>
```

If you want something that looks exactly like the "profile box", you can do that too. In fact, using `{include}` you can create `profilebox.tpl` and use it in both places to reduce redundant code.